# How is an answered question closed for not being an answerable question?

Tags: discussion, closing

Some people jumped to close [my post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25211/are-there-any-easter-eggs-in-video-games-still-hidden-today), even though it was answered, favorited, and someone said it was an "interesting question".

Instead of closing it, why would you not first make suggestion on how the question can be improved?

I feel like this is an important part of any Stack Exchange community, and I've never had a question closed so instantly like this one.

If you need someone who asks the question to elaborate, ask them to elaborate. If you think something is wrong with it, leave a comment so they can change it.

The fact that I can't do anything with this question now makes me highly upset, as the answer to it was great, yet it was closed for no reason.

The criteria for closing questions shouldn't be this easy, and I think, if there is an answer to the question and some people are showing interest, it's impossible that it can be: a) not an answerable question, and/or b) not a real question.

Is there a better way to handle this issue?

I really think that "close first, ask for clarification to reopen later" is the wrong philosophy, guys. Any way to mark it for closing if the author doesn't make an accepted change to it in X days?

Comment: As for the speed - we have many users and little questions, so each gets _many_ eyeballs _fast._

Comment: I understand that, but give the author of a question the chance to fix a question. If it can't be fixed, delete it. The thing is, my question isn't total nonsense, it's a legitimate question (that received a legitimate answer before being closed!!), so I don't see how this can be allowed to happen? I'm not trying to start fights, I just really think this was the wrong act here. Rather than help me, the question was slid under the carpet. If I were anyone who didn't know how this site worked and had never asked a question before, this would alienate me from ever coming back. You know?

Comment: @Aero The question is closed, not deleted. You're still in time to fix it. I've been helping you fix it. What's the problem with that? Raven e.g. commented that he couldn't think of a way the question could be salvaged. You gotta respect that.

Comment: Sorry if I said deleted, I meant closed! And you did help me fix it. I appreciate that. And no, I can't respect and the idea of the question not being able to be "salvaged". It seems like an easy reason to get rid of a question. Even before we "fixed" it, there was an entirely accepted and respectable answer to it.

Comment: @Aerodynamo After a question has been closed, it can still be reopened. Closing is not necessarily indefinite. Basically, it's not our way of 'getting rid' of questions. That's deleting them, and that happens very rarely.

Comment: If you got the answer you were looking for (and thus accepted it), why are you worried that the question is closed?  What is your goal in having the question reopened?

Answer (score 8):

So, I think there was some good discussion in the comments to your question (most of which you disagreed with), but let's try and drill down a little further and see what people were getting at:

Your original question was:

> Are there examples of one such easter egg being found in a game years later its release?

To which Mana responded:

> This question is very broad...any valid answer would have to be updated pretty much every week

Raven went on to clarify

> don't see a possibility for any real answers to this question

Now I can see where you're coming from: `If there were no real answers, how did it get answered?` and I think this is a good point.  Raven wasn't being very clear, and neither was Mana.  Now that might be because they're long standing members and for each of them what they said was enough to explain the idea they were getting at, so allow me to elaborate on what I think they were trying to say:

**Every easter egg is an equally valid answer to this question, so no one answer can be considered "THE" answer**

I think this is a good point.  On a serious question and answer site, there needs to be an Authoritative answer.  Something people can reference as the correct answer to a question.  This can be tough as many questions are open ended, or vague.  Now obviously you weren't looking for a complete list of all Easter Eggs every found ever (or even unfound), you just wanted an example of one (and you got a REALLY good example).  Unfortunately, the example is not authoritative.  I cannot point to it as *the* answer for people searching for easter eggs.

I realize this was a mild curiosity for you, and your life is enriched for the experience, but for a site trying to be a serious Q&A site its just not helpful and, in fact, its kind of detrimental.  It establishes a flavor of *yahoo answers*; a brand the site is trying very hard to avoid.

---

Now there is also a separate issue here.  Your question got closed without protracted discussion.

That's largely a result of this site being community run.  Much like wikipedia, what is created and destroyed is handled largely by the community and not by moderators.  Since we're dealing with a broad community we cannot just legislate how long a discussion must progress before a vote is cast.  Instead, we allow people (who have demonstrated sufficient involvement via rep) to vote when they feel it is appropriate.  Five such people felt closing your question was appropriate.

Now I understand you disagree with them, and the proper forum to discuss such disagreement is here on **meta**, but you cannot scold the overall community for not allowing a protracted discussion; well you can, but nothing will come of it.

---

If you'd like to discuss more on why this question was closed I'll try to help you see the opinion expressed by the members of the community (though I did not close it, I would have had it been open when I found it).

Comment: Well said. I've also learned from this experience that I should refrain from commenting shortly after waking up.