# 'Sounds like a List question' = subjective votes?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently asked [How can I identify games that use Pando Media Booster, and is there a workaround to download the installer without it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/76527/25150) where I also wanted to know which games use it (clearly explaining why it was relevant). This quickly attracted 3 down votes because it 'sounds like a list question', in hindsight I could have perhaps rephrased the question title - but its obvious (to me atleast!) from the actual description that this is **not** the case.

Fine, I understand there is a general hostility to any sort of lists here, which is perfectly fine - when in Rome etc., and I should expect downvotes even if I'm asking for useful info as it goes against some site policy.

Then I come across [What are the names of all rank levels in Bejeweled 3 and Bejeweled Blitz?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/what-are-the-names-of-all-131-rank-levels) , mainly due to the recent edit to clear up the title. As far as I'm aware, the 'no list questions' policy has been in place/consideration [from 2010](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/776/voting-on-the-future-of-list-of-x-questions), before the question was posted. Still, this question (which seems ***very clearly*** to be a list) has received only upvotes.

Now I'm confused as to what constitutes the grave offence of asking for a list, or what are the exceptions where it is allowed. I tried searching on Meta, and despite a lot of discussion the category itself seems to be ill defined.

Thus, I have a few questions (not a list!) on what constitutes a list and should be downvoted:

- Is there a single clear description of what is considered to be the kind of list question that is discouraged (official policy, highly upvoted answer/comment on meta etc.)
- What would be the specific exemptions to the general policy. e.g. if a list is being asked so that people can avoid potential problems, is that allowed? Some examples:

  - What are games that use `<problem software>` so I can avoid/be wary of them?
  - [Where do the enemies for the unique enemy achievements spawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/70103/25150) (note the upvotes and general usefulness of the answer)
  - [Is there a list of the 'levels allowed' range for joining public games of a particular quest and difficulty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/69664/25150) : again, no downvotes in this case; and it actually *asks* for a list
- When I encounter older list questions, should I be downvoting them or bringing them up in chat for reconsideration?

Comment: Found http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/624/re-evaluating-our-site-what-is-the-scope-of-an-acceptable-list-if-it-exists which is my first question (give me clear guidelines on what is good & bad) ... I think the discussion there gave up on it :p

Comment: For your "Where do the enemies spawn" question - the answer is finite, objective, and only one can be correct/complete. The experts in the community are able to vet the quality of the answer. Same with the level range question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key thing to note that is different between the list you asked for and the other examples you cite is that those other lists are inherently *limited* in scope to the individual games in question. Your question is an *unbound* list, which has no clear limit on the number of items it will contain, which is the sort of list that's problematic.

This has been a 'settled discussion' for something of a while now, but here are a few particularly relevant links:

[List questions for The Old Republic / MMOs -- CW, closure, other?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other?rq=1)

[Can we get these obviously off-topic questions closed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/can-we-get-these-obviously-off-topic-questions-closed)

[How is an answered question closed for not being an answerable question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/how-is-an-answered-question-closed-for-not-being-an-answerable-question)

Comment: The comments on the KOTOR question actually point out its an unbounded list due to the nature of MMOs :p. Though the distinction does help - also, thanks for the title update to avoid upsetting itchy trigger fingers ;). I would really love a single answer that gives all the criteria for a decision (unbounded/bounded etc.), already went through several of the meta discusssions but it still seems like a subjective topic :/

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/31612/25150 is an example of unbounded list (with only upvotes). So even the unbounded criteria seems to be subjective (though I agree that its a good one, I will keep it in mind)

Comment: @Alok That's not a list at all. It's a question that asks for a numerical answer. The fact that the answer is 'infinite' is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

We consider "List *of games* that fit the X criteria" questions to be game-recommendation questions and thus automatically off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - but in this case, it wasn't to get recommendations but avoid potential problem (or make it easier to deal with). So while I understand LessPop's explanation about unbounded list being an issue, still can't get why just asking 'games that will make me install X' was bad in this case.

Comment: @Alok: How can the community judge the quality of a *single* answer for that question? How can anyone know what answer is correct? The SE engine works for specific questions with a single correct answer - this is the opposite.